# Can someone explain this proof of the determinant of a matrix product to me?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A and B are square matrices of order n, then det(AB) = det(A)det(B).

Proof:

Observe that E is an elementary matrix. If you obtain E from I by interchanging two rows, |E| = -1. If you obtain E by multiplying a row of I by a nonzero constant c, then |E| = c. If you obtain E by adding a multiple of one row of I to another row of I, then |E| = 1. Additionally, if E results from performing an elementary row operation on I and the same operations performed on B, then the matrix EB results. It follows that |EB| = |E||B|.

I just don't get last line; how does |EB|=|E||B| follow from that? How does this prove what we're trying to prove?

Comment: This is a very poorly written proof.  I think you should just find another source for the proof of this proposition, especially considering how easy it is to find one.

Comment: It's the one in my book lol. But I thought about it some more and I think I get it now anyway, at least enough.

Comment: You can find good proofs on the internet or in other books.